# HSQLDB and double byte chars

Tags: hsqldb, double-byte

I need to store double byte chars (Japanese Kanji) in an in-memory DB within a Java EE web app.

I'm considering using HSQL.

Will it support double byte chars?

Comment: What encoding will you be using? HSQLDB is in UTF-8 by default, unless you specify otherwise. Then each Kanji char would take up 3 bytes, is that problematic?

Comment: I don't believe so. So I would just have to ensure that I setup my columns size correctly to consider Kanji? i.e. CHAR(21) will allow 7 kanji symbols if I leave as UTF-8. The DB will need to store the address reference data in both English and Kanji.

Comment: HSQLDB always uses Unicode UTF-16, which is double byte per character.